# Слеш в конце url

Tags: url, .htaccess, php

Есть конструкция в `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)/$ index.php?blog_name=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}
```

На выходе получаются урлы вида: `http://site.zon/name/`, но если убрать слеш в конце, то получается 404-я, т.е. `http://site.zon/name = 404`.

Как это можно исправить средствами `PHP` или того же `RewriteRule`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.
RewriteRule ^(.*) %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

попробуйте так. Данный скрипт будет перенаправлять ваш с адреса без слеша на адрес со слешем (который в конце).

Comment: ухты-ухты.
помогло. и отлично работает.
спасибо Вам, lampa.

Comment: есть одна странность: на главной теперь два слеша: //
как от этого избавиться?

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [L,R=301]
```

Мне помогло.

> Источник http://interestabout.blogspot.com/2011/02/url-htaccess.html

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.